# How to append/delete data from JSONField in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-models

I have a `JSONField` which has some data like this :

```
{'key_one' : 'val_one',
 'key_two' : 'val_two'}
```

I want to add data to it as well as deleting data from it.
So far i can just give it a value not appending to it.

I'm using `mySql` database

Comment: Are you using this library: https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield?

Comment: no, I'm using the JSONField that comes with MySQL 5.7

Comment: What have you tried so far for appending/deleting a key?

Comment: RTFM? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For appending to `JSONField` or any other JSON in `python` :

```
my_json = {'key_one' : 'val_one',
           'key_two' : 'val_two'}
```

same as  :

```
my_json = Model.objects.get(pk=id).my_json_field
```

Append to `json` :

```
my_json['new_key'] = 'new_val'

print (my_json) 

 {'key_one' : 'val_one',
  'key_two' : 'val_two',
  'new_key'  : 'new_val'}
```

Delete from `json` :

```
my_json.pop('new_key')

print (my_json) 

 {'key_one' : 'val_one',
  'key_two' : 'val_two'}
```